# Generate a library (.lib) file

Tags: c++, static-libraries, .lib

1. I want to build Libharu and generate a static library (.lib) file. I am using ***VS2010***.
2. I want to build Libharu with `ZLIB` and `Libpng` support. I have already installed them and `zlib.lib` and `libpng.lib` are present in **Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/lib**
3. I followed the installation method for **Windows platforms (except cygwin/MinGW)** as mentioned [on this official link](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Installation)

   - I used `nmake -f script/Makefile.msvc` which generated `.obj` files
   - then to check the success, I ran `nmake -f script/Makefile.msvc demo`, which successfully created the demo Pdfs

**Question:** How do I generate `.lib` file with `zlib.lib` and `libpng.lib` support?

**PS:** 
1. [Link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm) for ZLIB installation

2. [Link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm) for Libpng installation

**UPDATE:** By doing the above mention steps, i get the following output on console

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        if exist *.lib del *.lib
        lib -out:libhpdf.lib src\hpdf_utils.obj  src\hpdf_error.obj  src\hpdf_mmgr.obj  src\hpdf_list.obj  src\hpdf_streams.obj  src\hpdf_objects.obj  src\hpdf_null.obj  src\hpdf_boolean.obj
  src\hpdf_number.obj  src\hpdf_real.obj  src\hpdf_name.obj  src\hpdf_array.obj  src\hpdf_dict.obj  src\hpdf_xref.obj  src\hpdf_encoder.obj  src\hpdf_string.obj  src\hpdf_binary.obj  src\hpd
f_encrypt.obj  src\hpdf_encryptdict.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef_tt.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef_type1.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef_base14.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef_cid.obj  src\hpdf_font.obj
src\hpdf_font_type1.obj  src\hpdf_font_tt.obj  src\hpdf_font_cid.obj  src\hpdf_doc.obj  src\hpdf_info.obj  src\hpdf_catalog.obj  src\hpdf_page_label.obj src\hpdf_gstate.obj  src\hpdf_pages.o
bj  src\hpdf_page_operator.obj  src\hpdf_destination.obj  src\hpdf_annotation.obj  src\hpdf_outline.obj  src\hpdf_image.obj  src\hpdf_encoder_jp.obj  src\hpdf_encoder_kr.obj  src\hpdf_encode
r_cns.obj  src\hpdf_encoder_cnt.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef_jp.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef_kr.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef_cns.obj  src\hpdf_fontdef_cnt.obj  src\hpdf_image_png.obj  src\hpdf_image_ccitt.obj  s
rc\hpdf_doc_png.obj  src\hpdf_ext_gstate.obj  src\hpdf_namedict.obj  src\hpdf_3dmeasure.obj  src\hpdf_exdata.obj  src\hpdf_u3d.obj
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Comment: And you're using VS?

Comment: yes, I am using VS2010

Comment: Just looking at the makefile they should already be linked in: https://github.com/libharu/libharu/blob/master/script/Makefile.msvc#L35

Comment: @Hayt: Sorry, I didn't get you. I need to get a `.lib` file which I can use for other program. But I do not receive any `.lib` file with the steps that I mentioned above.

Comment: ah ok. If you have errors it is always helpful to also put the error messages in your question.

Comment: There is no error. The steps that I have mentioned, they just generate the `.obj` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the environment variables `ZLIB_PREFIX` and `PNG_PREFIX`  to the according folders they are installed in **before** you run the makefile

The scripts expects the folder `PNG_PREFIX\include` and `PNG_PREFIX\lib` to be existent (so set the variables to the folder both these folders are in).

The same goes for `ZLIB_PREFIX`.